# what's wrong with start1()?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

Does anyone know what's wrong with start1()? I know that something is not right but I just can't figure what is it. 
I have got this school project where i need to do a quiz and record the time that people need to answer all the questions. I've tried everything i know but nothing works. please help

```
  <body>
    <div id="classic">

        <input type="button" onclick="start1= setInterval(contador, 1000)" value="yes">
        <input type="button" onclick="back1()" value="Menu">
        </div>
     <div id="quizr"  hidden>
      <h1> who sings the song </h1>


  <div id="P1">  
   <p>1.'Thinking Out Loud'</p>
    A)<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1r1" > Hozier<br>
    B)<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1r2" > Jason Derulo<br>
    C)<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1r3" > Ed Sheeran<br>
    D)<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1r4" > Mr. Probz<br>
   <br>  
   <input type="button" onclick='go1()' value="next »" > 
  </div>

<div id="P2" hidden>  
   <p>2.'GANGNAM STYLE'</p>
    A)<input type="radio" name="q15" id="q15r1" > Tori Kelly<br>
    B)<input type="radio" name="q15" id="q15r2" > Jessie J<br>
    C)<input type="radio" name="q15" id="q15r3" > Beyoncé<br>
    D)<input type="radio" name="q15" id="q15r4" > Psy<br>
    <br>
   <input type="button" onclick='verify1= clearInterval(start1)'value="submit">
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="result" hidden></div>
```

---

```
 function start1()
     {
       document.getElementById("classic").hidden=true;
       document.getElementById("quizr").hidden=false;
     }

  var t= 0;
     function contador() 
     {
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = ++t;
     }

  function go1()
    {
     document.getElementById("P1").hidden= true;
      document.getElementById("P2").hidden = false;
    } 
  function verify1()
    {
     document.getElementById("P2").hidden = true;
     document.getElementById("result").hidden = false;

     var correctAnswers= 0;
     var question1 = document.getElementById("q1r3").checked;
        if (question1 === true)
          {
           correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
          }
       var question2 = document.getElementById("q2r4").checked;
        if (question2 === true)
          {
           correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
          }

          document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = correctAnswers + "/15" + " " + " correct" + " "+ "answers";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a `readonly`. See the docs:

> [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes)
>
> Is a Boolean attribute indicates that the element is not yet, or is no longer, relevant. For example, it can be used to hide elements of the page that can't be used until the login process has been completed. The browser won't render such elements. This attribute must not be used to hide content that could legitimately be shown.

What you must really do is:

```
document.getElementById("classic").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("quizr").style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: that part was right until i had "setInterval(contador, 1000)" to start1 and  "clearInterval(start1)" to verify. so i think the error is in this part i just don't know what is it.

Comment: @sara What are you trying to do then?

Comment: I'm doing a quiz and i want people to see the time they needed to answer the quiz. the time should appear after the click the button verify. I'm not sure if i'm making myself clear

Comment: @sara Can you show the code somewhere live? Like using jsbin, or jsfiddle?

Comment: @sara The link doesn't work! `:(` It shows a username and password field. What am I supposed to put in them?